# How to add a url config file for Vue project

Tags: vue.js

Is there any possible to add a config file for Vue project to config API URL?

Now I have a Vue web project, and a .Net Web API project.

I have to build the web project every time that I have to publish to different environment.

Is there any possible to add a config file like web.config for .Net Web API that I can edit it any time I want?

***What I expected is, I can have a file to edit anytime I want after run command 'npm run build'. Is this possible***

Comment: If you use `webpack`, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310260/vue-js-build-with-different-environment-variables

Comment: It only able to config 2 different URL and for develop and production.
But what I want is to config different URLs for production, which is the package after 'npm run build'

Answer (score 5):

yes you can add config file if you use webpack

/config/prod.env.js

```
module.exports = {
NODE_ENV: '"production"', // or development
BASE_URL: '"https://BASEURL/"',
API_URL: '"https://APIURL/"',
}
```

Assig in build file and use

```
process.env.API_URL
```

reference : https://alligator.io/vuejs/working-with-environment-variables/

Comment: This is only able to edit before command 'npm run build'.
Is there any possible to add a file to edit it after command 'npm run build'?

Comment: IN node need to rebuild compile and compack app js. that why npm run build important for that you can try with node super user. it use for collection of files to watch for changes https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor